# C++ - Template parameter deduction failed from subclass

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I'm trying to use a subclass from an other class as parameter for template function:

```
template<typename T> class Class1{

public:
    class Sub1{};

};

template<typename T> class Class2{

public:
    Class2() = default;

    template<typename T_other> void func(const typename Class1<T_other>::Sub1 sub) {}

};

// ...code

Class1<int>::Sub1 sub1;
Class2<float> class2;
class2.func( sub1); //ERROR
```

The error says:

```
error: no matching function for call to ???Class2<float>::func(Class1<int>::Sub1&)???
         class2.func( sub1); //ERROR
                          ^
note: candidate: ???template<class T_other> void Class2<T>::func(typename Class1<T_other>::Sub1) [with T_other = T_other; T = float]???
         template<typename T_other> void func(const typename Class1<T_other>::Sub1 sub) {}
                                         ^~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ???T_other???
```

What is wrong? The error message says the correct type (`Class1<int>::Sub1`)so why can't it deduce it?

Comment: That is what is called non-deduced context. Will try to find a dupe, there should be a lot.

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you! I see. Is it not possible at all to make it work like this? Do I need to explicitly say the type?